# How to trigger a lambda function after completing aws CodeDeploy?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-code-deploy

I want to trigger my lambda function before terminating original instances by aws CodeDeploy.

Comment: one way to set instance life cycle hook, trigger lambda when the instance event is `EC2_INSTANCE_TERMINATING` https://docs.aws.amazon.com/autoscaling/ec2/userguide/lifecycle-hooks.html

Answer (score 1):

It can be done by adding a trigger in the deployment group

CodeDeploy > Applications > Application name > Deployment groups